# Is there anyway to access the variables inside the object in this example?

Tags: javascript

So I have recently been learning about objects and methods in JavaScript and wrote this little example to help me understand things like "this" and methods a bit more.

```
objectTest = function() {
    this.test = 1;
    this.test2 = 2;
};

thisThing = new objectTest

thisThing.test3 = [1,2,3];

objectTest.prototype.whatIsThis = function(){
    console.log(this.test);
};

thisThing.whatIsThis();
```

The output of the above code is `1` which makes sense because it refers to the `this.test`, which i defined in the object.

Now what if i wrote `objectTest` like this:

```
objectTest = function() {
    var test = 1;
    var test2 = 2;
};
```

If i `console.log(this);` in my `whatIsThis` Method i will simply get: 
`Object { test3=[3], whatIsThis=function()}`

I am curious is there anyway for me to access the value of test and test2 without writing something like:

```
objectTest = function() {
    var test = 1;
    var test2 = 2;
    return "test is" + test + "and test2 is" + test2;
};
```

Also if this is possible what would be a practical example of needing to do something like this?

Comment: No. Variables aren't directly tied to the instances being created. Properties are. `test = 1` actually [defines a global](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript), which is why it may seem to work once. But, you'll have collisions with every instance trying to set and use the same globals.

Comment: Note, if you return a string from a function and then try to use that function with the `new` keyword, then you won't get that string back. You'll get an object.

Comment: Ah right i should have used var. But would that change anything would i still be unable to access test and test2?

Comment: @AndrewFont No, you wouldn't be able to access them elsewhere. Constructors act like any other function with regards to local variables -- they're only accessible within the `function` itself. The only way to extend access to them is [via closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures).

Comment: Do you have anything against using `this.test` inside constructor? If you're just trying out things and seeing what happens, then you've just seen that not using `this.varname` inside constructor function doesn't make those variables available in _instances_ of function created using `new` keyword. Are we missing something?

Comment: Yea this was a question of curiosity. I want to know IF it was possible. I have no applicable use for something like that. But thank you all for the answers =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking, since your "What if?" example doesn't come with any justification.

However, you're nudging close to something interesting in JS and that's the implementation of 'private' variables.

For a prototype call `objectTest`:

```
objectTest = function() {
    var test = 1;
    var test2 = 2;
};

var ot = new objectTest();
```

`test` and `test2` are, effectively, private variables, in that they are not accessible via the instance `ot`.

However, they're not accessible *at all*, so something like:

```
objectTest.prototype.getTest = function () { // ... };
```

can't be implemented, such that it provides access to `test`, since `test` is not a property of `this` when `getTest` is invoked against `ot`.

What to do... what to do?

Well, you could do this:

```
objectTest = function() {
    var test = 1;
    var test2 = 2;

    this.getTest = function () { return test; };
    this.setTest = function (val) { test = val; };
};

var ot = new objectTest();
```

These will work because `test` is available via a closure over `getTest` and `setTest`. `test` is still not a property of `ot`, so you have your private variable that can only be modified via your getter and your setter.

### Update

The variables `test` and `test2` are local to the function `objectTest`. That means, on each invocation of `objectTest`, they are created anew.
Thus, new instances of `objectTest` objects do *not* share these values.

Comment: Ok, this makes allot of sense now. Out of curiosity, if i use 'ot.setTest(3)' from your example, am I changing the value of 'test' for all instances of 'objectTest'. So for example if I had 'ot2.getTest' would i return '3' or would i return the starting value of '2'